# How long does a boto3 session persist? In my service, I'm looking to get instance from multiple regions and thinking of creating a session for each

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm very new to boto library and I'm not sure if I can create a session and resource everytime there's an api call to my service which in turn gets the instances from ec2 or create a session once and persist. I'm not passing any tokens or anything. Couldn't find anything in docs.

Answer (score 2):

You're right. The documentation is not very enlightening here.

Sessions encapsulate configuration (such as credentials, region, and endpoint). I would generally create one session per configuration tuple, outside of my API route handling, so that it can be re-used.

Comment: Thanks! So, I can create it globally while starting the service and persist for all further calls?

Comment: Yes, that's a typical pattern common to Flask apps and Lambda functions, for example.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks much.